# remove header from a CSV in Google Cloud Funciton

Tags: csv, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am Creating a `CSV` File from a `Google Cloud Big Query Table`.
Since I am converting the entire table into a CSV, by default the **`table header`** name is Included in the CSV file.

This is the Code I am using for creating the `CSV file`

```
  // Export data from the table into a Google Cloud Storage file
  const [job] = await bigquery
    .dataset(datasetId)
    .table(tableId)
    .extract(storage.bucket(bucketName).file(filename), options);

  console.log(`Job ${job.id} created.`);
```

I have tried the following code to use to remove the header, did it doesn't work

```
const parser = csv({ headers : true });
```

Any Idea how I can remove the header from the CSV??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [`printHeader` option in the API definition](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#JobConfigurationExtract). In the NodeJS client library, you can find the definition in the [IJobConfigurationExtract](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/main/src/types.d.ts)

So, use `printHeader:false` in the `options` object